# StringBuilder giving me false value while comapring two stringbuilder object with same value?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

As I read `equals()` method is used to compare string in java for equality but when i run this code i am getting output false . why?

```
public class TestStringBuilder {
 public static void main(String[] str){
    StringBuilder sb1= new StringBuilder("Hello World");
    StringBuilder sb2= new StringBuilder("Hello World");
    System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In String builder since there is no `.equals()` method overridden so this calls the Object `.equals()` method
which equates for object reference instead of its value.

While in String class this has been overridden to compare value at each position and then return the result

Here is the Overridden `.equals()` method from String class which is self Explanatory why it's happening so

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
       if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
       }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
           int n = count; //count is the length of return in the docs
            if (n == anotherString.count) {
                char v1[] = value;//The value is used for character storage.
               char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = offset; //The offset is the first index of the storage that is used.
                int j = anotherString.offset;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                       return false;
               }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must compare for equality the strings contained in `StringBuilder`  and not the builders themselves :

```
System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString()));
```

This will return true

Answer (score 0):

equals() is overridden in String and primitive wrapper classes. Its not ovrrriden in StringBuilder, hence its checking for same reference, which is false.